# Why lighting appears on opposite side?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, light

I am trying to build lighting using [this](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting) tutorial. However, lighting appears on wrong side of human object and  I do not know why.

Normals were created per triangle. Vertices of a triangle basically have the same normal:

```
glm::vec3 calculateNormal(glm::vec3 vertice_1, glm::vec3 vertice_2, glm::vec3 vertice_3)
{
    glm::vec3 vector_1 = vertice_2 - vertice_1;
    glm::vec3 vector_2 = vertice_3 - vertice_1;
    return glm::normalize(glm::cross(vector_1, vector_2));
}
```

Here is code for vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
out vec4 vert_color;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform vec4 color;

void main()
{
    vert_color = color;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * transform * vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
    FragPos = vec3(model * transform *  vec4(pos, 1.0));
    Normal = normal;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 lightColor;

in vec4 vert_color;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    float ambientStrength = 0.1;
    float specularStrength = 0.5;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(cameraPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, Normal);

    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor; 

    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * vec3(vert_color.x, vert_color.y, vert_color.z);
    frag_color = vec4(result, vert_color.w);
}
```

Main loop:

```
    wxGLCanvas::SetCurrent(*glContext);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glm::mat4 model, view, projection;
    model = glm::translate(model, modelPos); // modelPos is 
    view = fpsCamera->getViewMatrix();
    projection = fpsCamera->getProjectionMatrix(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    color = glm::vec4(0.310f, 0.747f, 0.185f, 1.0f);
    glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 lightColor = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glm::mat4 phantomtTransformation;
    phantomtTransformation = glm::rotate(phantomtTransformation, - glm::pi<float>() / 2.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    phantomtTransformation = glm::rotate(phantomtTransformation, - glm::pi<float>() , glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram.loadShaders("Shaders/phantom.vert", "Shaders/phantom.frag");

    glClearStencil(0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    shaderProgram.use();
    shaderProgram.setUniform("transform", phantomtTransformation);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("model", model);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("view", view);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("projection", projection);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("lightColor", lightColor);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("lightPos", lightPos);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("cameraPos", fpsCamera->getPosition());

    
    glStencilMask(0xFF); // Write to stencil buffer
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);  // Set any stencil to 0

    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF); // Set any stencil to object ID
    m_pantomMesh->draw();
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);  // Set any stencil to 0        // no need for testing

    glFlush();
    wxGLCanvas::SwapBuffers();
```

View from front of the object:

[image]

View from back of the object:

[image]

**EDIT:**
In order to debug I removed object rotation matrix from main loop:

```
 glm::mat4 phantomtTransformation;
    phantomtTransformation = glm::rotate(phantomtTransformation, - glm::pi<float>() / 2.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    phantomtTransformation = glm::rotate(phantomtTransformation, - glm::pi<float>() , glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
 
shaderProgram.setUniform("transform", phantomtTransformation);
```

and changed line in fragment shader from

```
frag_color = vec4(result, vert_color.w);
```

to

```
frag_color = vec4(Normal, vert_color.w);
```

in order to visualize Normal values. As a result I noticed that when camera changes position phantom also changes color which means that normal values are also changing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your vertex shader you are not applying any transformation to the normal. Its just saying Normal = normal. You should be rotating the normal direction by the models rotation value ( no scaling or translating since its a direction ) I don't have time to read through this thoroughly right now but I would wager that's the source of the problem

Comment: @Joey , I did multiply normal vector with rotation matrix but it did not help.  `Normal = transform * normal;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of your problem is that you are not applying your model transformation to your normal vectors. Since you definitely do not want to skew them, you will have to create a special matrix for your normals.

As is explained further down the tutorial that you mentioned, the matrix can be constructed like this

```
Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
```

in your vertex shader.
**However**, I highly recommend that you calculate the matrix in your application code instead, since you would calculate it per vertex in the above example.
Since you are using the glm library, it would look like this instead:

```
glm::mat3 model_normal = glm::mat3(glm::transpose(glm::inverse(model)));
```

You can then load your new `model_normal` matrix into the shader as a `uniform mat3`.